# Goose Gone Fishing

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, language

```
There once was an Austrian gander
Who had made his way down to Flanders
One fine day he wished
That he could go for a fish 
So he went to the store
They took him backdoor
And had him break a hive full of bees!
```

Why would they make the poor goose do this?

Hint 1

> The goose had it coming.

Hint 2

> He really was an angel though.

Hint 3

> Press edit...

Hint 4

> What would he have asked for at the store which would invite such a response?

Hint 5

> What would he have asked for at the store given that he wanted to go fishing?

Hint 6

> What would the gander be a *victim* of by breaking the hive?

Hint 7

> See the new tag.

Hint 8

> He got what he asked for.

Hint 9

> The goose thought the shopkeeper was his friend.

Hint 10

> The shopkeeper, you could say, was a false friend of the gander.

Hint 11

> What could be said about this miscommunication?

Update:
I am adding another hint and giving one last shot for anyone to get the 100% correct answer, but if nobody gets it I will mark the closest answer (There is one which is very close).

Comment: I'm confused. Are you sure this is a puzzle?

Comment: Quite sure although this is my first crack at making one. There’s another tag I could add which is relevant but it would be a dead giveaway.

Comment: obviously rot13(gur tbbfr ubaxrq va Trezna naq gur fubcxrrcre gubhtug ur jnf fcrnxvat Qhgpu-tbbfr naq zvfhaqrefgbbq guvaxvat ur jnagrq ubarl.  Hasbeghangryl, V pna'g svaq Trezna-tbbfr gb Qhgpu-tbbfr genafyngbef gb cebir guvf.)

Comment: I don't think it's part of the puzzle but rot13(vgf shaal gung gurer'f yvgrenyyl n ohapu bs trrfr fcrpvsvp gb Nhfgevn gung ner pynffvsvrq nf gur beqre 'nafre'!)

Comment: Well, rot13( gung'f n cyhf sbe gur pbafvfgrapl bs guvf ceboyrz gura!)

Comment: So the whole language riddle is about one single word which in the given context is hardly to be confused with its false friend? I was hoping and searching for a clever formulated  question/sentence beeing misunderstood in another language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Credits to @Levieux for figuring out the exact terms.

The goose was honking..

> in German (spoken in Austria) but the store keeper spoke Dutch (language in Flanders). However, the German word for **fishing rod** "angel" means **bee stinger** in Dutch.
>  Thus, the unfortunate incident.

Disclaimer:

> I speak neither of these languages and had to rely on Google Translate so it may be a bit off. The main thought should (hopefully) hold true though.

Comment: rot13(Lbh ner irel pybfr. Frr gur arj uvag.)

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Updated the answer with my best shot. It probably isn't rot13(tenzzngvpnyyl pbeerpg ohg V qba'g unir gvzr gb yrnea gur ireo pbawhtngvbaf bs gjb ynathntrf :C)

Comment: rot13(V’yy fnl gung lbh unira’g tbg nal ubggre.  Creuncf jvgu fbzr gvzr/nabgure uvag.)

Comment: rot13(Irel avpr gel gubhtu)

Comment: I’ve half a mind to accept this because it is quite close, and nobody else seems to have an answer.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog rot13(Fubhyq jr or ybbxvat gb pbafgehpg n pbzcyrgr Trezna/Qhgpu fragrapr? Be vf gur snpg gung gur tbbfr nfxrq sbe n svfuvat ebq (Natry va Trezna) naq tbg n orr fgvatre (natry va Qhgpu) vafgrnq fhssvpvrag?)

Comment: @Levieux rot13(It is sufficient, being able to construct such a sentence is a bonus. (Vg vf fhssvpvrag, orvat noyr gb pbafgehpg fhpu n fragrapr vf n obahf. (V nz abg 100% fher vs vg vf cbffvoyr fvapr V'z abg n angvir fcrnxre bs rvgure ynathntr))

Comment: Okay, thank you. In that case I will leave it to @greysaff to edit their answer, as it's such a small change.

Answer (score 7):

The gander wanted to go

> trout-fishing

and needed

> some [bee-moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphomia_sociella) larvae as [bait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxworm#Waxworms_as_bait).

The store

> was sold out.

So

> they found an infected bee hive and broke it open to collect the larvae.

This is

> **definitely a thing you should not do!**

*Something makes me think Im way too literal...*

Comment: Very nice attempt. And just a bit too literal.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go for a stretch.

> The goose wanted to go fly fishing.

But

> There was a misunderstanding, and the folks at the store took this to mean that the goose wanted to catch flies instead of fish.

And

> So goes the adage, "You catch more flies with honey ..."

Because of course

> There is honey found inside the bee hive.